# HTML - Jump to an iframe

Tags: html, anchor

I have a series of links like so

```
<li><a href="classes/journeydistance.html" target="classes">Class Name </a></li>
```

That goes to this iframe

```
<IFRAME src="classes/yaddayadda.html" style="width:400px;height:700px;" frameborder="0" name="classes" scrolling="auto">
</IFRAME>
```

However the iframe is at the bottom of the page, the links are at the top with a bunch of text in between.  Is there a way to make it so when the person clicks the class link it jumps them to the iframe?

Comment: :D Yes! Gimme a sec I wanna try something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution: (using a touch of javascript)

http://jsfiddle.net/RGjCL/4/

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)"
            onclick="IFrameScroll('http://www.asdf.com')">Class Name</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function IFrameScroll(link){
        window.classes.location=link; 
        window.location.hash='classes'
    }
</script>
```

Comment: hmmm this isn't working for me either, the iframe doesn't even show up.

Comment: Doesn't show up? Did you click on the link: `http://jsfiddle.net/RGjCL/4/`   The code in my answer is just a sample of how the javascript would work

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by giving the iframe an id an put a hashtag in the link:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" rc="classes/yaddayadda.html" style="width:400px;height:700px;" frameborder="0" name="classes" scrolling="auto"></iframe>
And the link: <li><a href="classes/journeydistance.html#myIframe" target="classes">Class Name </a></li>
```

I haven't tested it but I think it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok my initial idea was quickly crushed (wanted to do a pure html/css thing using a trick which on second thought was pretty stupid).

Since you're already triggering an action with the anchor (a tag) you can't do much more with it unless you use javascript.

So here is a working proof of concept with jquery http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/Wpnng/2/

This way the links will still work if js is turned off it just wont scroll down...

I don't think there is a way in just html/css, I wouldn't use jquery if this is the only thing you would be loading it for...

Made a slight improvement, targetting w/e is in the target attribute of the link in question being clicked, however, if you always want to scroll to the same iframe this would just make it slower: http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/Wpnng/3/

Comment: Ok, I edited the css file to match... put in the links as per the example and attached the javascript file to the site... and it still doesn't work.  Ive checked to make sure that javascript is turned on and tried it in firefox and ie...

Comment: @JosepthVodary you will need to have jquery loaded too or it indeed will not work. If you don't want to host the js library yourself you could use this code with a google api link `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js"></script>`